# How to group column values into 'others'?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a huge list of website names in my dataframe.
e.g array(['google','facebook','yahoo','youtube', and many other small websites])
Dataframe has around 40 more websites.
I want to group the other websites name as 'other'
My input table is something like

```
|Website      |
|-------------|
|google.com   |
|youtube.com  |
|yahoo.com    |
|nyu.com      |
|something.com|
```

My desired output will be something like

```
|Website    |
|-----------|
|google.com |
|youtube.com|
|yahoo.com  |
|others     |
|others     |
```

I tried a few things but didn't work. Should I be manually renaming them ? Or is there any way, I can create a new column and mention them as others with a few exceptions as above ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did your query solved?

Comment: @AnuragDabas Yes it was solved.

Comment: if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved(click onthe tick to make it green). If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether

Comment: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
m=df['Website'].isin(['google.com','youtube.com','yahoo.com'])
#Finally:
df.loc[~m,'Website']='others'
```

OR

```
m=df['Website'].str.contains('google|youtube|yahoo')
#Finally:
df.loc[~m,'Website']='others'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `str.contains`:

```
df.loc[df['Website'].str.contains('google|youtube|yahoo|facebook'),'Website']='others'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
# maintain a list of sites you wish to keep
sitesToKeep = ['google.com', 'youtube.com', 'yahoo.com']

# for all rows where the value in the column 'Website' is not present in the list 'sitesToKeep' change the value to 'other'
df.loc[~df.Website.isin(sitesToKeep), 'Website'] = 'Other'
```